# How to alert from a text type to a mediumtext type and does not affect original data?

Tags: mysql, text, types, schema, alert

I found MySQL text type has 64k limit, and for my application, it's not enough, so how do I migrate from text to mediumtext? I also want to keep my original data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alter table foo modify column bar mediumtext;
```